# iPhone Autorotation - Disable view rotation animation BUT transitions to another screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am currently working on an app where I would like to transition from one screen to another when the user rotates the device to landscape view. I have this working, but the screen that is being transitioned out rotates to landscape view just as the next view is coming in. A common solution to preventing the current view from rotating is to return NO for the shouldAutoRotate method. However, I need this enabled in order to transition to the next screen. I've also toyed with [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO] in the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation but this only hides the animation, and still rotates the current view to landscape. Here are all related rotate methods:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
        return YES;
}

//Temporarily disable rotation animation
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];

    if(UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"landscapeView" sender:self];
}


-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the view that is animating out at rotation time to not respond to changes in orientation/size. See, for example, your autolayout settings in interface builder, or possibly the struts/springs settings, if you're not using autolayout (which a newer technology).